# How to search a string in dump file using extension dll using windbg?

Tags: dll, windbg

Basically need a cpp program to create an extension dll and this dll should search specific string/ASCII character in dump file.

Comment: What is your answerable programming question? Please (re)view [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: a) Such functionality is already available in WinDbg. b) It's a bit slow, so if you don't know whether the string will be found or not, try [Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings) first

Comment: look at IDebugDataSpaces4::SearchVirtual2